# MySQL query with OR returning only subset of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query i run on a db table

```
SELECT *, CONVERT_TZ(`received_on`, '+00:00','+05:30') AS received_on 
FROM `user_chat_msgs` 
WHERE (`from_user`='54610' AND `to_user`='1') 
OR (`to_user`='1' AND `from_user`='54610') 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10000;
```

This returns only messages like

**from_user= 54610 and to_user=1**

Expected Result

**from_user= 54610 and to_user=1** OR 
**from_user= 1 and to_user=54610**

Logically query sounds correct to me and i am not sure what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use the appropriate `where` clause:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT_TZ(`received_on`, '+00:00','+05:30') AS received_on
FROM `user_chat_msgs`
WHERE (`from_user` = '54610' AND `to_user` = '1') OR
      (`from_user` = '1' AND `to_user` = '54610')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

Your `where` clause:

```
WHERE (`from_user` = '54610' AND `to_user` = '1') OR
      (`to_user` = '1' AND `from_user` = '54610')
```

simply repeats the two conditions, but in a different order.

Note:  if the user id is a number, then don't use quotes around the constants.

Comment: if you read fully "WHERE (`from_user`='54610' AND `to_user`='1') OR (`to_user`='1' AND `from_user`='54610') "

Comment: what is the exact reason for this ordering ? both sounds correct to me

Comment: Your original query has 2 clauses which are exactly the same, just with the columns being checked in a different order. Gordons query corrects this so the first clause checks both combinations